# How to do conditioned substring in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table [dbo].[LogActionItems] which looks like:

```
ItemParam
 Jméno = [Výber_s_orezem3], Název pole "Od" = [OD], Název pole "Do" = [DO], Interval "Od" = [1.10.2016], Interval "Do" = [31.10.2016], Orezat = [True], Podmínka = [OSCIS='26767'], Vstupní tabulka = [CELPRAC], Výstupní tabulka = [tmp_CELPRAC_pomoc],
```

I want to extract the string behind "Jmeno =" without the "[]".
So the expected output would be value "Vyber_s_orezem3".

Comment: This seems like the problem is your data; you are storing denormalised data. SQL Server's ability to parse strings is poor at best, so you you would be far better off doing this outside of SQL Server, or (better yet) switching to a normalised design (then the solution would be to simply `REPLACE` the characters).

Comment: SQL is a query language, not a text manipulation language. SQL has very limited text manipulation functionality and what you ask requires either regular expressions or a parser. Clean the data *before* inserting it into SQL Server

Comment: Even if you find a way to parse this data you won't be able to use indexes to accelerate this query. If you have a table with 10K rows with such data, every time you try to find `Výber_s_orezem3` the server will have to parse *all* rows and check for that text.

Comment: Do you always want the string contained inside the first set of `[square brackets]`? Or the string inside the square brackets that correspond to `Jméno`? Or something else? Please help define the logic (and also give us a hand and tell us what version you're using - that's `SELECT @@VERSION;` not Help > About in SSMS).

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE  (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ItemParam NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (ItemParam) VALUES
(N'Jméno = [Výber_s_orezem3], Název pole "Od" = [OD], Název pole "Do" = [DO], Interval "Od" = [1.10.2016], Interval "Do" = [31.10.2016], Orezat = [True], Podmínka = [OSCIS=''26767''], Vstupní tabulka = [CELPRAC], Výstupní tabulka = [tmp_CELPRAC_pomoc],');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID, value
    , Result = TRIM(' []' FROM RIGHT(value, LEN(value) - pos))
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ItemParam, ',')
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('=', value)) AS t(pos)
WHERE value LIKE N'Jméno%';
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------------------------+-----------------+
| ID |           value           |     Result      |
+----+---------------------------+-----------------+
|  1 | Jméno = [Výber_s_orezem3] | Výber_s_orezem3 |
+----+---------------------------+-----------------+
```